# Getting default styles when upgrading from React Navigation v4 to v5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am currently using React Navigation v4 and migrating to v5. I am using the [official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/upgrading-from-4.x.html) for the upgrade but unfortunately, I encountered a blocker.

In V4 I can do the following:

```
export default function ExampleScreen(props) {
  return <View></View>
}

ExampleScreen.navigationOptions = ({navigation, navigationOptions}) => ({
  headerStyle: {
    ...navigationOptions.headerStyle,
    borderBottomWidth: 0
  },
  headerRight: () => <SearchBox navigation={navigation} />
})
```

But in V5 I can't seem to access the `navigationOptions` parameter so I can't get the `navigationOptions.headerStyle`.

```
export default function ExampleScreen(props) {
  props.navigation.setOptions({
    headerStyle: {
      // I can't get the default styles here.
      borderBottomWidth: 0
    },
    headerRight: () => <SearchBox navigation={props.navigation} />
  })

  return <View></View>
}
```

How can I do this in React Navigation V5 as it was not documented anywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the defaults into a variable and export it. Then import where you need it and use:

```js
export const headerStyle = {
  /* whatever */
};

// Use in `screenOptions`
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerStyle }}></Stack.Navigator>;

// Use in `setOptions`
navigation.setOptions({
  headerStyle: [headerStyle, { borderBottomWidth: 0 }],
  headerRight: () => <SearchBox navigation={props.navigation} />
});
```